# Grouping polygons based on existing Travel Time Matrix

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-plugins

I have a number of polygons within a regional boundary (~600 polygons), and I also have a separate travel time matrix (table/csv) for these polygons that is 600x600 (time it'll take to reach each polygon from one polygon). My goal is to try to reduce the total number of polygons within the regional boundary, meaning, I'd like to aggregate these polygons into polygons that are traversable within 5 minutes. I am using QGIS.

What I have done so far is, in R, I've aggregated the polygons by grouping polygons that are within 5 minutes of a specific polygon. If I go to the next polygon, and that one is already aggregated as part of a larger polygon, I skip it and go to the next one. Until all of them are grouped (this is done using the travel time matrix csv, nothing spatially is done). I then to go to into QGIS and use dissolve, multiparts to singleparts, clipping, difference, and centroid to nearest hub, to group the polygons that were unable to be joined initially.

Is there a better way to aggregate these polygons by using a travel time threshold? How can I attach the travel time matrix to the original polygon shapefile to group the polygons that fall within a 5 minute travel time threshold?

**What I did in R (detailed):**

From the 600x600 matrix table, I instead made it into a table with ~360K rows, where the columns were the Origin, Destination, and Travel Time. I then looped through each unique polygon ID (600 polygons) and checked for the polygons that are within 5 minutes of that [origin] polygon, and assigned those a unique group ID. For example, let's say we have zone 1, and zones 1,2,3 are within 5 minutes of zone 1. Then we assign zones 1,2,3 an ID of 1. Then we go to zone 2, but zone 2 is already aggregated, so we skip it and go to zone 3, same thing. When we get to zone 4, we check to see which zones are within 5 minutes. Let's say that zones 2,3,4,5, and 6 are within 5 minutes of zone 4. However, we've already aggregated zones 2 and 3, so we ignore them and just assign 4,5,6 a unique group ID. Hope that helps to clarify things.

Comment: Struggling to understand this precisely. Are you trying to compute, for each polygon, the polygons that can be reached within 5 minutes? And then, in QGIS, have some way of selecting a polygon and displaying the polygons that can be reached in 5 minutes? What does your aggregated data structure in R look like?

Comment: I've added a more detailed explanation to what I did in R above, hope that helps to clarify things a bit better. What I'd like to do is essentially group the polygons into 5 minute zones. All that matters to me is that they are continuous zones, so little to no gaps. After the output from R, I go into QGIS to dissolve, multi part to single part, and then I assign the single parts that weren't grouped to the closest polygon based on distance. Happy to answer any other questions to help clarify things a bit.

Comment: Am I right in thinking your ID assignments will depend on the order that the zones appear in the data? In your example, if 2 and 4 had been the first two zones, they would have ended up with the same ID (because you say they have < 5m travel time) instead of different ones (because 2 has already been aggregated to 1 when you get to dealing with 4)?

Comment: Yes that's correct. This is something that I initially had not thought of when I first went into this problem, but I have the zones ordered by the ID. However, this does not necessarily mean that they will always be spatially continuous based on this order, since I'm taking the unique zone ID's from the matrix.

Comment: Okay, I was just trying to see if your algorithm described any standard clustering or graph partition algorithm but mostly they are order-independent by design (because why should the order matter to a partitioning?).

Comment: No. I don't employ any machine learning or anything like that, since I don't really have the knowledge or experience. My method is relatively simple, once I do the dissolve, and add the individual single parts to the existing multipart based on closest distance, the grouped polygons don't necessarily remain in 5 minute zones anymore (become +1 to +2 minute zones [6-8 minute zones] depending on the travel time). Also, because of that, the zones throughout the region don't necessarily have the same travel time.